# psycopg2 cursor hanging on terminated Redshift query

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, amazon-redshift

I am using psycopg2 (2.6.1) to connect to Amazon's Redshift.

I have a query that should last about 1 second, but about 1 time out of every 20 concurrent tries it just hangs forever (I manually kill them after 1 hour). To address this, I configured the statement_timeout setting before my query, as such:

`rcur.execute("SET statement_timeout TO 60000")`
`rcur.execute(query)`

so that after 1 minute the query will give up, and I can try again (the second try does complete quickly as expected), but even with this (which I confirmed worked by setting the timeout to 1 ms and seeing it raise an Exception), sometimes the Python code hangs instead of raising an Exception (it never reaches the `print` directly after the `rcur.execute(query)`). And I can see in the Redshift AWS dashboard that the query has been "terminated" after 59 seconds, but my code still hangs for an hour instead of raising an Exception.

Does anyone know how to resolve this, or have a better method of dealing with typically short queries that occasionally take unnaturally long and simply need to be cancelled and retried?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43594310/244297

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to configure your keepAlive settings for the Redshift connection.
Follow the steps in this AWS doc to do that,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html